# Sql Server create an alert when a scheduled job can not be started because it is already running

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql server job that is scheduled to run every 3 hours. Occasionally, the job takes longer than 3 hrs. In that case, the next scheduled run does not occur.

I would like to setup sql server to alert me if this conditions occurs and perhaps log the condition.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an automatic way to do this.  You'll need to put some code into the job step so that if is runs for over 3 hours it alerts you.  The easiest way would be to capture the start time and end time do a date diff on it, then send an email, or log an alert to the errorlog.